# Draw impossible figure with MMA, how can it be done?

Tags: graphics, code-request, generative-art

How can I draw this figure using Mathematica? I have tried to trace the points on it but the white lines or contours that they have distort the resulting figure.

I have searched for some similar code but it did not work for this figure.[image]

---

This is reminiscent of Escher's work, but after sufficient staring, this picture can be broken into three identical rotated sections.

[image]

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Edit**

Since `TernaryListPlot` is new in 13.1 version,for old version,we use `ternary[{p1_, p2_, p3_}] = {p1 + 1/2 p2, Sqrt[3]/2 p2};` to translate the ternary-coordinate to normal Cartesian coordinate and do the same thing.

```
Clear[n, m1, m2, m3, pts1, pts2, pts3, ternary];
(* for all versions  *)
n = 19;
m1[k_][{x_, y_, z_}] = {x, y + k, n - (x + y + k)};
m2[k_][{x_, y_, z_}] = {x + k, y, n - (x + k + y)};
m3[k_][{x_, y_, z_}] = {n - (y + k + z), y + k, z};
pts1 = ComposeList[{m1[6], m3[-3], m1[7], m3[-5], m2[1], m3[7], 
    m1[-7], m3[2], m1[9], m3[-4], m2[1], m3[6], m1[-17], m3[-1]}, 
   m2[1]@{0, 0, 1}];
pts2 = ComposeList[{m1[1], m3[1], m2[-1], m3[-2]}, pts1[[8]]];
pts3 = ComposeList[{m1[8], m3[1], m1[-9], m2[1]}, pts2[[3]]];
{pts1, pts2, pts3} = {pts1/n, pts2/n, pts3/n};
ternary[{p1_, p2_, p3_}] = {p1 + 1/2 p2, Sqrt[3]/2 p2};
Graphics[{EdgeForm[{AbsoluteThickness[2], White}], Red, 
  Polygon /@ Map[ternary, {pts1, pts2, pts3}, {2}], Yellow, 
  Polygon /@ Map[ternary@RotateLeft[#, 1] &, {pts1, pts2, pts3}, {2}],
   Green, Polygon /@ 
   Map[ternary@RotateLeft[#, 2] &, {pts1, pts2, pts3}, {2}]}]
```

[image]

**Original**

We use `TernaryListPlot` and define three transformations `m1,m2,m3` to move the point parallel to the three edges respectively.

```
Clear[n, m1, m2, m3, pts1, pts2, pts3];
n = 19;
m1[k_][{x_, y_, z_}] = {x, y + k, n - (x + y + k)};
m2[k_][{x_, y_, z_}] = {x + k, y, n - (x + k + y)};
m3[k_][{x_, y_, z_}] = {n - (y + k + z), y + k, z};
pts1 = ComposeList[{m1[6], m3[-3], m1[7], m3[-5], m2[1], m3[7], 
    m1[-7], m3[2], m1[9], m3[-4], m2[1], m3[6], m1[-17], m3[-1]}, 
   m2[1]@{0, 0, 1}];
pts2 = ComposeList[{m1[1], m3[1], m2[-1], m3[-2]}, pts1[[8]]];
pts3 = ComposeList[{m1[8], m3[1], m1[-9], m2[1]}, pts2[[3]]];
(* TernaryListPlot[{pts1, pts2, pts3}, Joined -> True] *)
TernaryListPlot[{pts1, pts2, pts3}, Frame -> False, PlotStyle -> None,
  GridLines -> {Subdivide[0, 1, n]}, GridLinesStyle -> Gray, 
 Prolog -> {EdgeForm[{Thick, White}], Red, 
   Polygon /@ {pts1, pts2, pts3}, Yellow, 
   Polygon /@ Map[RotateLeft, {pts1, pts2, pts3}, {2}], Green, 
   Polygon /@ Map[RotateLeft[#, 2] &, {pts1, pts2, pts3}, {2}]}]
```

[image]

```
TernaryListPlot[{}, Frame -> False, 
  Epilog -> {EdgeForm[{Thick, White}], Darker@Green, Polygon[pts1], 
    Polygon@pts2, Polygon@pts3, Polygon[RotateLeft /@ pts1], 
    Polygon[RotateLeft /@ pts2], Polygon[RotateLeft /@ pts3], 
    Polygon[RotateLeft /@ pts1], Polygon[RotateLeft /@ pts2], 
    Polygon[RotateLeft /@ pts3], Polygon[RotateLeft[#, 2] & /@ pts1], 
    Polygon[RotateLeft[#, 2] & /@ pts2], 
    Polygon[RotateLeft[#, 2] & /@ pts3]}] /. 
 Line[pts_] :> {White, Line[pts]}
```

[image]

**Appendix**

I also test `AnglePath`,but it seems it is not easy to find the rotation center.

```
n = 19;
Graphics[
 Line[AnglePath[{{6/n, π/3}, {3/n, -2 π/3}, {7/n, 
     2 π/3}, {5/n, -2 π/3}, {1/n, π/3}, {7/n, 
     2 π/3}, {7/n, 
     2 π/3}, {2/n, -2 π/3}, {9/n, -π/3}, {4/
      n, -2 π/3}, {1/n, π/3}, {6/n, 2 π/3}, {17/n, 
     2 π/3}, {1/n, π/3}}]]]
```

Comment: Ha! (+1) I just suggested such a method in replying to a comment, before I knew anyone else had responded. Doing it this way felt to me deserves a consultant's fee, so I opted for the easy way. :)

Comment: @cvgmt,hi,What version of MMA do you use, I have 12 and the result presented by you does not occur.

Comment: @padre `Ternary ListPlot` is new in 13.1 version. We can also use the low version to do this, but need time to revised the code.

Comment: @padre Please see my updated.

Comment: @cvgmt: I determined the center of rotation in your try with `AnglePath` - see my answer.

Answer (score 20):

This is based on @cvgmt's unfinished try with `AnglePath`.
And also using, I think, more appropriate coloring - based not on three different rotations of one object but on orientation of each plane.

```
n = 19;
c = {17/38, 1/(2 Sqrt[3])};
p1 = AnglePath[{{6/n, π/3}, {3/n, -2 π/3}, {7/n, 
     2 π/3}, {5/n, -2 π/3}, {1/n, π/3}, {7/n, 
     2 π/3}, {7/n, 
     2 π/3}, {2/n, -2 π/3}, {9/n, -π/3}, {4/
      n, -2 π/3}, {1/n, π/3}, {6/n, 2 π/3}, {17/n, 
     2 π/3}, {1/n, π/3}}];
p2 = Rest@
   AnglePath[{{7/n, π/3}, {2/n, -2 π/3}, {1/n, 
      2 π/3}, {1/n, π/3}, {1/n, π/3}}];
p3 = Rest@
   AnglePath[{{7/n, π/3}, {1/n, -π/3}, {8/n, π/3}, {1/
       n, π/3}, {9/n, 2 π/3}}];
r1 = RotationMatrix[2 π/3];
r2 = RotationMatrix[4 π/3];
color = ColorData[97, "ColorList"];
obj = Polygon;
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], {color[[1]], obj[# - c & /@ p1], 
   obj[r1 . # & /@ (# - c & /@ p2)], 
   obj[r2 . # & /@ (# - c & /@ p3)]}, {color[[2]], 
   obj[r1 . # & /@ (# - c & /@ p1)], obj[r2 . # & /@ (# - c & /@ p2)],
    obj[# - c & /@ p3]}, {color[[3]], 
   obj[r2 . # & /@ (# - c & /@ p1)], obj[# - c & /@ p2], 
   obj[r1 . # & /@ (# - c & /@ p3)]}}]
Clear[n, c, p1, p2, p3, r1, r2, color, obj]
```

[image]

And this is composed of simple lines using `color = {Black, Black, Black}; obj = Line;` in the above code:

[image]

**Update:**

```
trans[x_] := 
 Module[{n = Length /@ Cases[Split[x[[2]]], {0 ..}][[{1, 2, -1}]]},
  {x[[1]] - 9*{1/2, 1/(2 Sqrt[3])}, {-a, b, 
    Sequence @@ Table[0, n[[1]] + 9], -b, 
    Sequence @@ Table[0, n[[2]] + 9], a, b, 
    Sequence @@ Table[0, n[[1]] + 9], b, 
    Sequence @@ Table[0, n[[3]] + 9]}}]

a = π/3;
b = 2 a;
r = {IdentityMatrix[2], RotationMatrix[2 a], RotationMatrix[2 b]};
t = AnglePath[{{1, a}, {1, -b}}] // Mean;
{m1, m2, m3} = {6, 4, 7};
p1 = {{-9, -7}*t, {-a, b, Sequence @@ Table[0, m1], -b, 
    Sequence @@ Table[0, m2], a, b, Sequence @@ Table[0, m1], b, 
    Sequence @@ Table[0, m3]}};
p2 = trans[p1];
p3 = trans[p2];
p4 = trans[p3];
ap1 = AnglePath @@ p1;
ap2 = AnglePath @@ p2;
ap3 = AnglePath @@ p3;
ap4 = AnglePath @@ p4;
q1 = Most[Insert[Drop[ap2, {23, -25}], Splice[Most[ap1]], 9]];
q2 = Most[Insert[Drop[ap3, {23 + 9, -25 - 9}], Splice[q1], 9]];
q3 = Most[Insert[Drop[ap4, {23 + 2*9, -25 - 2*9}], Splice[q2], 9]];
c = ColorData[97, "ColorList"];
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], 
  Table[{c[[k]], Polygon[r[[k]] . # & /@ Most[ap1]]}, {k, 3}]}]
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], 
  Table[{c[[k]], Polygon[r[[k]] . # & /@ q1], 
    Polygon[r[[k]] . # & /@ ap2[[24 ;; -25]]], 
    Polygon[r[[k]] . # & /@ (r[[2]] . # & /@ 
        Most[AnglePath[ap2[[9]], {-a, 0, b, a, a}]])]}, {k, 3}]}]
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], 
  Table[{c[[k]], Polygon[r[[k]] . # & /@ q2], 
    Polygon[r[[k]] . # & /@ ap3[[24 + 9 ;; -25 - 9]]], 
    Polygon[r[[k]] . # & /@ (r[[2]] . # & /@ 
        Most[AnglePath[ap3[[9]], {-a, 0, b, a, a}]])], 
    Polygon[r[[k]] . # & /@ ap2[[24 ;; -25]]], 
    Polygon[r[[k]] . # & /@ (r[[2]] . # & /@ 
        Most[AnglePath[ap2[[9]], {-a, 0, b, a, a}]])]}, {k, 3}]}]
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], 
  Table[{c[[k]], Polygon[r[[k]] . # & /@ q3], 
    Polygon[r[[k]] . # & /@ ap4[[24 + 2*9 ;; -25 - 2*9]]], 
    Polygon[r[[k]] . # & /@ (r[[2]] . # & /@ 
        Most[AnglePath[ap4[[9]], {-a, 0, b, a, a}]])], 
    Polygon[r[[k]] . # & /@ ap2[[24 ;; -25]]], 
    Polygon[r[[k]] . # & /@ (r[[2]] . # & /@ 
        Most[AnglePath[ap2[[9]], {-a, 0, b, a, a}]])], 
    Polygon[r[[k]] . # & /@ ap3[[24 + 9 ;; -25 - 9]]], 
    Polygon[r[[k]] . # & /@ (r[[2]] . # & /@ 
        Most[AnglePath[ap3[[9]], {-a, 0, b, a, a}]])]}, {k, 3}]}]
Clear[n, a, b, r, m1, m2, m3, t, p1, p2, p3, p4, q1, q2, q3, c, ap1, ap2, ap3, ap4]
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: (+1)  The colors theme is very good.

Comment: azerbajdzan, thanks , very good

Answer (score 11):

Easy way:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/zC0NX.png"];
ImageGraphics[Binarize[Last@ColorSeparate[img], 0.67], 
 DominantColors[img][[;; 2]], Method -> "Exact"]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, it is possible in the same code to vectorize the image so that it does not pixelate on the edges

Comment: @padre The result is in fact vector graphics. The rough edges come from the `ImageGraphics` algorithm and the noisy edges. If you use the option `Method -> "LinearSeparable"`, `ImageGraphics` will do some smoothing, but the result is not too good because of the noise along the edge in your image. That's why I stressed "easy" and not "good." There is probably a way to straighten the edges in the image, but it might not be easy (and I don't know how). Probably the most straightforward way is to lay out an equilateral triangular grid and determine the vertices by hand.